# Maven: Read file and loop through contents

Tags: maven, properties, compilation

So I have 2 files that have a list of other files that I would like to package.  This is what the directory would look like

```
 /mydir   
   |-pom.xml   
   |-a.out   
   |-b.out   
   |-c.out 
   |-d.out  
   |-read1.list  
   |-read2.list
```

Here are the contents of read1.list and read2.list

read1.list

```
a.out
b.out
```

read2.list

```
c.out
```

So I'd like maven to read the read1.list and read2.list files, take the list of files, and copy them to another directory.  I think I have the reading of the files part but I don't know what to do after that.

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <executions>
       <execution>
          <id>read property file</id>
          <phase>process-resources</phase>
          <goals>
             <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
             <files>
                <file>${basedir}/read1.list</file>
                <file>${basedir}/read2.list</file>
             </files>
          </configuration>
       </execution>
    </executions>
 </plugin>
```

I got this code from this post but I was unsure what to do next.
[Maven: Read property file and copy resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40928224/maven-read-property-file-and-copy-resources)

Any help would get greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should not violate the convention over configuration paradigm and put those files simply into `src/main/resources` directory and then the will automatically picked up and being packaged into the resulting jar file...without any supplemental configuration....and you can also remove the whole properties-maven-plugin configuration...

Comment: @khmarbaise  This is not a java project.  It's a simple scripts directory.